# Export JAR with libraries

Tags: eclipse

I have eclipse.

I can export jar with libraries (Export->Java->Runnable JAR file->Copy required libraries into a sub-folder next to the generated JAR).

Exported libs puts into projectName_libs folder. Can I change (in eclipse) folder name for exported libs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure you can do it out of the box with Eclipse. However, you can manually rename the folder and then change the contents of the `/META-INF/Manifest.mf` file (`Class-Path:` entry) changing all the `projectName_libs` into `yournewdirectory`.

Comment: OK, you may be able to do it strictly with code, as you have the whole eclipse available as Java classses. Also, it seems it is a known "misfeature" not allowing to configure the directory. See for example: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=243163#c7